# 2 Nested for loops, 2 variables (1 from a csv) & Unexpected Results

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I've been puzzling over why this for loop won't generate the expected results - for their to be 1 matching entry that generates a 'yes' output.  Can anyone help point out my error?  The csv that I'm importing has 7 columns & 17,000 rows.  "alle" is also imported from a csv to list with with 4 elements - each of which is a list of 6 elements.  I'm using Python2.7 & I realize I'm opening more libraries than I need, but I am new & didn't want to remove any that could break the code before posting this.

"alle" elements look like:

```
['Danlaw Inc',  'Applications Engineer',  'Novi, MI', 'http://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=e199589101464b99',  'Novi',  'MI']
```

Rows of the csv file look like:

```
['4318055', 'Brownsville', 'LA', 'Brownsville, LA', '32.48709', '-92.1543', '4317']
```

Here's my code:

```
import math
import csv
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json
from json import load 
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from time import sleep

f = open(r'C:\Users\****\*****\Python\Best City Pop Long Lat Data\UScities1000_Trimmed_Full_NoHeader.csv', "rb")
csv_f1 = csv.reader(f)

for a in alle:
    for e in csv_f1:
        if a[2] == e[3]:
            print ('yes')
```

I have confirmed that both lists have the matching entry (which is a city & state - "Novi, MI"), but when I run the code I don't get any "yes" as output.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

UPDATE:

Here is how I'm appending the "alle" csv list variable that I think is causing the problem:

```
def splitter(element):
    city,state=element.split(', ',1)
    return city, state

#   >>>>>  Assign variable to input city

#cities = []
#location = []



for e in alle:
    if ', ' in e[2]:
        city,state = splitter(e[2])
        #location = [[city],[state]]
        #e.append(location)
        e.append(city)
        e.append(state)
```

Comment: Where is `alle` being read in/created - in one of the `import`s? Have you tried printing all of the `a[2]` and `e[3]` pairs to see if this is what you expect?

Comment: Please provide a raw dump of the first few lines of the csv file. There is a comma in "Novi, MI". Are fields in the csv file quoted?

Comment: Your problem statement is simple (maybe too simple) and seems complete and amenable to optimization. But as mentioned, the code is "too simple to fail", so we are all suspicious of some piece of hidden code creating bad data. Can you provide some data dumps?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies.  The about code is from a much larger program and I don't want to repost all.  I haven't solved the problem, but I believe I know what's causing it.  In my program I'm trying to append new information to the list variable I created from the csv.  For some reason this is screwing up the data that was stored in the variable (seems to delete or replace it?).  Did I import the data incorrectly from the csv in the code above?  Is there another format / syntax that makes the data easier to work with? / not disappear when I append things to the list variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.  The way I was reading data from the csv file into the list variable was the culprit - although I don't know the exact reason.  However, the below works:

```
alle=[]

with open(r'C:\Users\****\******\Recruiting Business\Proximity Project\AllDailyCIJobs 26thJan10_12-30daysNoHeader.csv', "r+b") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        alle.append(row)
```

This is what I was trying to use before:

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\****\******\Recruiting Business\Proximity Project\AllDailyCIJobs 26thJan10_12-30daysNoHeader.csv', "rb")

alle = csv.reader(f)
```